# How can you find the most common sets using python?

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a pandas dataframe where one column is a list of all courses taken by a student.  The index is the student's ID.

I'd like to find the most common set of courses across all students. For instance, if the dataframe looks like this:

```
ID    |     Courses
1           [A, C]
2           [A, C]
3           [A, C] 
4           [B, C]
5           [B, C]
6           [K, D] 
...
```

Then I'd like the output to return the most common sets and their frequency, something like:

```
{[A,C]: 3, [B,C]: 2}
```

Comment: [pandas.Series.value_counts()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) ?

Comment: That function returns the error: _TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'_

Comment: Well... because lists are kinda unhashable (beiing mutable) :-) Convert them to tuples, which is always better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# create example data
a = range(6)
b = [['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['K', 'D']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': a, 'Courses': b})

# convert lists in Courses-column to tuples (which some parts of pandas need)
df['Courses'] = df['Courses'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
print(df.Courses.value_counts())
```

Output:

```
(A, C)    3
(B, C)    2
(K, D)    1
Name: Courses, dtype: int64
```

**Edit (as my answer was accepted):**

jezrael describes (first as a comment to my answer) a much more compact version of the same approach:

```
a = range(6)
b = [['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['K', 'D']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': a, 'Courses': b})

print(df.Courses.value_counts())  # list->tuple and counting in one line!
```

Comment: You can remove `lambda`: `(df.Courses.apply(tuple).value_counts())`

Comment: Just wow. That's beautiful. If you would add this as a short answer, i would upvote. :-)

Comment: Using `numpy.unique` with `return_counts=True`is a fast way to count frequency:
`courses, freq = np.unique(df['Courses'], return_counts=True)
z = [tuple(x) for x in courses]
y = dict(zip(z, freq))`

Answer (score 5):

You can first convert `list` to `tuples` and then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Last use [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
print (df.Courses.apply(tuple).value_counts()[:2].to_dict())
{('A', 'C'): 3, ('B', 'C'): 2}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant code i saw today (which is a big improvement to my original approach)!